# StringSubstitutor not working with JSON text

Tags: java, json, text, string-substitution

I am trying to do some String Substitution using the StringSubstitutor . My payload is often JSOn and it doesnt replaces the token always.

Example

```
  String ss = "{\"media\":[{\"channels2\":\"[Token2]\",\"channels\":\"[Token1]\"}]}";
    final Map<String, Object> tokenReplacementValues = new HashMap<>();
    tokenReplacementValues.put("Token2", "33");
    tokenReplacementValues.put("Token1", "22");
    System.out.println("Tokens to tokenReplacementInstruction = {}" + tokenReplacementValues);
    StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(tokenReplacementValues, "[", "]");
    ss = sub.replace(ss);
    System.out.println("After Token Replacement: " + ss);
```

But when i print , only one token is replaced.

After Token Replacement: **{"media":[{"channels2":"[Token2]","channels":"22"}]}**

Tried with various options like different prefix, suffix and token names. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the nested `[`, the first token becomes `[{\"channels2\":\"[Token2]` which won't get replaced.

Without nesting I get:

```
Before Token Replacement: {"media":{"channels2":"[Token2]","channels":"[Token1]"}}
After Token Replacement: {"media":{"channels2":"33","channels":"22"}}
```

You should use a JSON processing library instead I guess.